# How to detect which 3rd sdk use UDID?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, appstore-approval, udid

We use a lot of third-party SDKs from ad providers, and since Apple will not allow UDID access after May 1st, I want to check which SDKs use the UDID function.  Is there a simple way or tool to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple and naïve method is to run `strings` and `grep` on the library files. i.e.

```
strings libSomething.a | grep uniqueIdentifier
```

If you see any line that prints exactly `uniqueIdentifier` there is a risk they call it. This method is not 100% bullet proof. But I'd expect Apple doing a similar check in their automatic validation.

Comment: I already tried this method and found some sdks (the latest version) still contains "uniqueIdentifier" methods, I'm not sure it is from [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] or it is just their own method.

Comment: @ocean How about just adding a breakpoint for uniqueIdentifier and see what happens?

Comment: @epatel You'll get rejected if uniqueIdentifier exists in your code/lib, even if you never call it. So a symbolic breakpoint doesn't help, if a lib/framework doesn't call it, but uses uniqueIdentifier in code!!!

Comment: @Fab1n it was just *one* suggestion, maybe that could show if another `Class` is calling it...anyway the SDK devs should update asap. Last week I **needed** to submit and did this *hack* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433621/libspotify-causing-apple-app-store-rejection/16491455#16491455 to pass the automated checks. In Review now...

Comment: @epatel crazy horse!!! :-) I only wanted to keep in mind, that runtime checks do not save you from being rejected. strings is by far now the best solution to find out which framework/lib is responsible for a rejection, so you don't have to update all of your libs, because that would probably mean a lot of time of adaption to the new api of these libs

Answer (score 1):

You could set a symbolic breakpoint for -[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try secureudid (secureudid.org)?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *uuid = nil;
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
if (theUUID) {
  uuid = NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID));
  [uuid autorelease];
 CFRelease(theUUID);
}
```

try this