# Can I check whether my app use UDID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, udid

I have integrated some SDK in my app, I'm not sure whether these SDK use the UDID.So I want to check it like apple does. any suggestion?

Comment: What SDK are you using? This could be the reason why you are checking but from the 1st May Apple will reject apps using the UDID. Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128828/what-can-be-used-with-uidevice-currentdevice/16099440#16099440 for alternatives to using the UDID.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997031/how-to-detect-which-3rd-sdk-use-udid

Comment: @Popeye thank you.I used wechat SDK.in fact my own app doesn't need the UDID.I just want to ensure the SDK I used are not using the UDID..

Comment: From what I can see of the wechat SDK. I can't see why they would use the UDID but to make sure `epatels` link is good for checking.