# Check UDID access in pre built library and strip that call without compiling again

Tags: iphone, ios, udid

Is there any way to confirm UDID is not accessed in pre built library?

For example: I have google Admob iOS sdk. How can I confirm that below API is not used in this library?

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Also is there any way to remove only this line of code from pre built library?

Comment: You can use the find text in the project.

Comment: no, I have only libary file (lib.a) file

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: In general...say its any ads sdk...is there any way to find?

Comment: usually No, you cant look at the implementation of the library.

Comment: but if you are using a known library, you can check if they have launched a newer version of that library and if yes then integrate that one.

Comment: I had the same problem but with libspotify, did a non-recommended *hack* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433621/libspotify-causing-apple-app-store-rejection only for special circumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check through terminal:

```
strings libSomething.a | grep uniqueIdentifier
```